# Concatenate all the data using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to get the data of the prioritize element. I have a condition, need to get the `<AAA>` first if it is not null. Else, I will get the data from the `<BBB>`. The parent element `<ParentElem>` of `<BBB>` can occur many times, so, for example, I have 3 `<ParentElem>`, I need to concatenate all the value of `<BBB>`. Below is my XML File in which the `<AAA>` element is NULL. In that case, I will get the value from the `<BBB>` element.

**INPUT**

```
<RootElem>
    <DataRec>
        <Struc>
            <AAA></AAA>
        </Struc>
        <ParentElem>
            <Docu>
                <BBB>11111</BBB>
            </Docu>
        </ParentElem>
        <ParentElem>
            <Docu>
                <BBB>22222</BBB>
            </Docu>
        </ParentElem>
        <ParentElem>
            <Docu>
                <BBB>33333</BBB>
            </Docu>
        </ParentElem>
    </DataRec>
</RootElem>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<ID>111112222233333</ID>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(/RootElem/DataRec/Struc/AAA)='')">
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="/RootElem/DataRec/Struc/AAA"/>
            </ID>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(/RootElem/DataRec/ParentElem/Docu/BBB)='')">
            <xsl:for-each select="/RootElem/DataRec/ParentElem">
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(./Docu/BBB)"/>
                </ID>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how to do the concatenation for every occurrence of `<BBB>`. Is it possible to do it in XSLT? I am using XSLT 2.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/RootElem">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="DataRec/Struc/AAA[normalize-space()]">
            <ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="DataRec/Struc/AAA"/>
            </ID>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="DataRec/ParentElem/Docu/BBB[normalize-space()]">
            <ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="DataRec/ParentElem/Docu/BBB"/>
            </ID>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Working demo:
(a) http://xsltransform.net/94AbWCc
(b) http://xsltransform.net/94AbWCc/1

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is perhaps

```
<ID>
  <xsl:value-of select="(.//AAA/text(), string-join(.//BBB, ''))[1]"/>
</ID>
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Kay for the feedback.